# Residue at infinity of $\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^{2n+1}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$$\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^{2n+1}}$$
Am I right that limit as z approaches infinity does not exist? So its residue at infinity is equal to $c_{-1}$ of Laurent series. How am I supposed to get Laurent series of this function? Where is it centered? What range?

So  $$e^{z^2}z^{-2n-1}$$ should somehow get to $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}{A_k(z-z_0)^k}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The residue at infinity of an analytic function $f$ is the residue at $0$ of $\frac{-1}{z^2}f\left(\frac1z\right)0$. In the case of the function that you mentioned, it's the residue at $0$ of$$\frac{-1}{z^2}\times z^{2n+1}e^{\frac1{z^2}},$$which is easy to compute, since$$e^{\frac1{z^2}}=1+\frac1{z^2}+\frac1{2!z^4}+\cdots$$

Comment: Dear Teacher, ıs it possible to check my solution, if You have a few minutes..?? Thank you very much..  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3043357/460967

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, one finds residues of differentials, not of functions.
Here the differential is
$$\alpha=\frac{\exp(z^2)}{z^{2n+1}}\,dz$$

To find the residue at $\infty$, set $z=1/w$ and expand in powers of $w$. The coefficient of $w^{-1}\,dw$ is the residue.

Applying this to $\alpha$ gives
$$\alpha=w^{2n+1}\exp(1/w^2)\left(-\frac{dw}{w^2}\right)
=-\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{w^{2n-1}}{k!w^{2k}}\right)\,dw.$$
The coefficient of $w^{-1}\,dw$ is $-1/n!$, and that is the residue
of the differential $\alpha$ at $\infty$.